# Mysterious Errors in Monty Hall Python Code

Tags: python

I made a working Monty Hall program in Python (that proves the 2/3 to 1/3 chance), but when I made it in as few lines as possible, (a personal interest of mine) I get these mysterious errors! Here is the code:

```
from random import * 
i,a,abc,t,m=choice(['A','B','C']),raw_input('Switch? (y/n): ').upper(),['A','B','C'],0,0
for j in range(100):
    p = choice(abc)
    if ([y for y in abc if y not in [i,(choice([x for x in abc if x not in [i,p]]))]][0] if a == 'Y' else i) == p : t += 1
print 'WP: %i\nErrors: %i' %(t,m)
```

I recieved this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "fewlinesMonty.py", line 5, in <module>
    if ([y for y in abc if y not in [i,(choice([x for x in abc if x not in [i,p]]))]][0] if a == 'Y' else i) == p : t += 1
IndexError: list index out of range
```

So, I used a try/except to count the errors using this code:

```
from random import *
i,a,abc,t,m=choice(['A','B','C']),raw_input('Switch? (y/n): ').upper(),['A','B','C'],0,0
for j in range(100):
    p = choice(abc)
    try:
        if ([y for y in abc if y not in [i,(choice([x for x in abc if x not in [i,p]]))]][0] if a == 'Y' else i) == p : t += 1
    except: m += 1
print 'WP: %i\nErrors: %i' %(t,m)
```

The errors never exceed 10 %, but it makes no sense to me!

To fix the errors, all that is necessary is to define

```
o = choice([x for x in abc if x not in [i,p]])
```

and then replace the corresponding code with o .

I know the code is hard (kinda impossible) to read, but I appreciate any help/advice.

EDIT:
Here are what the variables mean:
i     = initial door choice (randomized)                                                                 x     = door to be opened (not prize, not initial)                                                      y     = door to be SWITCHED TO (not x, not initial)                                                             abc   = just A B and C in a list                                                                                 t     = total wins                                                                                                     m     = mysterious errors                                                                                          p     = door where the prize (or 'car') is

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: And... my head hurts. moving on...

Comment: When you have 7 brackets and parentheses in a row - `]]))]][` - you're not writing intelligible code. Stop trying to stuff all that into one line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is wrong with being a little more straight forward?

```
from random import choice
initial_guess, flip, wins=choice('ABC'),input('Switch? (y/n): ').upper()=="Y",0
for _ in range(100):
    actual_winner = choice('ABC')
    wins += 1 if (initial_guess == actual_winner and not flip) or (flip and initial_guess != actual_winner) else 0

print("WP: ", wins)
```

Run 1

```
Switch? (y/n): y
WP:  62
```

Run 2

```
Switch? (y/n): n
WP:  31
```

And if you really want the fewest lines:

```
from random import choice 
initial_guess, flip = choice('ABC'), input('Switch? (y/n): ') in ['y','Y']
print("WP: ", sum([[0,1],[1,0]][flip][initial_guess==choice('ABC')] for _ in range(100)))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Also, sorry for not noting what each variable means, I made them 1-character each so it would be possible to see the whole line at the same time. Anyway, here they are (although you already figured it out):     i = initial door choice (randomized)

Comment: Whoops, didnt mean to add those last two lines (my edits didnt save). Kudos to you for figuring out what they mean!

Comment: Also, you have the variable 'flip' as an input, it should be a raw_input. Great job though!

Comment: I was coding in Python3. it is `input` not `raw_input`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to RobertB for figuring this out, here it is: (I did make some *minor* edits)

```
from random import choice 
initial_guess, flip = choice('ABC'), raw_input('Switch? (y/n): ') in ['y','Y']
print "WP: " , sum([[0,1],[1,0]][flip][initial_guess==choice('ABC')] for i in range(100))
```